# How to get the array of the data in JSON - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json

Hello I was trying to get the array of the data which was written in JSON

For example this is my JSON object

```
{
    Data1 : {
        Data2 : "hello",
        Data3 : "hi"
    },
    Data4 : {
        Data5 : "this is Karan",
    }
}
```

I want the output as an array which contains `[Data1, Data4]`

Is there any way to do this Thank you

Comment: what about `Data2` and `Data3`..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop.

```js
var json = {
    Data1 : {
        Data2 : "hello",
        Data3 : "hi"
    },
    Data4 : {
        Data5 : "this is Karan",
    }
}

var keys = Object.keys(json);
console.log(keys);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in two ways. Either use `Object.keys` or you can use `for..in` loop to iterate the object and return push the keys in an array

```js
let data = {
  Data1: {
    Data2: "hello",
    Data3: "hi"
  },
  Data4: {
    Data5: "this is Karan",
  }
}

/**** OPTION -1 *****/

let getKeys = Object.keys(data);
console.log('Option-1 Result ', getKeys)

/**** OPTION -2 *****/

let keysArray = [];
for (let keys in data) {
  keysArray.push(keys)
};
console.log(keysArray)
```